# Missing icon when implementing IExplorerCommand

Tags: winapi, com, toolbar, explorer

I'm trying to extend my NSE with a toolbar button, but the icon I specified is never shown.
I return the icon location like shown in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
[This](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/sourcecode/windows/system/456836/FVCommands.cpp__.htm) example is doing it the same way.

Here is the source:

```
HRESULT MyExplorerCommand::GetIcon(
    IShellItemArray*,LPWSTR *ppszIcon )
{
  wchar_t iconPath[MAX_PATH+10];
  GetModuleFileName( moduleInstance,iconPath,MAX_PATH );
  wcscat( iconPath,L",-24" );
  return( SHStrDup(iconPath,ppszIcon) );
}
```

And that's my resource file:

```
24 ICON 24_info.ico
```

Text and tooltip are shown as expected, but I want an icon instead of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this ability has been removed in Windows 7.

In [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7) I found this:

> Icons on the command bar in Windows Explorer and common application
>   dialogs for Open/Save.